# Porque esto no funciona?

Tags: python, array, lista, bucle-for, function

Codigo mal:

```
def matriz(sistema):        
    for i in [0,1,2]:        
        sistema[1][i]=sistema[0][i]*(-sistema[1][0])+sistema[1][i]
        print(sistema[1][i], sistema[0][i])
    pass
pass
```

Salida:

```
[[1, 4, 3], [5, 2, 4], [2, 3, 1]]
0 1
2 4
4 3
```

Codigo que funciona:

```
def matriz(sistema):        
    for i in [0,1,2]:        
        sistema[1][i]=sistema[0][i]*(-sistema[1][0])
        print(sistema[1][i], sistema[0][i])
    pass
pass
```

Salida:

```
[[1, 4, 3], [5, 2, 4], [2, 3, 1]]
-5 1
20 4
15 3
```

Problema:
Parece ser que el mas en la primera función no devuelve el resultado esperado, mientras que en la segunda cuando le quito la suma a la declaración parece dar resultados coherentes.

Comment: podrias colocar cual es tu pregunta?? y el resultado esperado??

Comment: Mi pregunta seria ¿Cómo realizar operaciones con los elementos de una array? parece tonto pero no se porque no me dan los resultados, que deberian ser:
[[1, 4, 3], [5, 2, 4], [2, 3, 1]]
segunda fila 0 18 11
operacion
Fila2 = Fila1 * 5 - Fila 2

Answer (score 0):

No acabo de entender muy bien que es lo que pretendes hacer en tu función, solamente aclarar que el código que interpretas como malo, funciona como debería, lo que es más probable es que no acabes de entender que sucede.

Recomiendo añadir la siguiente linea dentro de la función:

```
print str(sistema[0][i])+"*(-"+str(sistema[1][0])+")+"+str(sistema[1][i])
```

De esta manera observarás, numéricamente, que está haciendo tu código y porque falla.

Espero haberte ayudado. Saludos y bienvenido!

Comment: Claro, el codigo que defino como malo, no entiendo porque hace lo que hace, no creo que este mal Python. Mi objetivo es que el elemento sistema[1][0] sea igual al producto  y la suma de otros elementos, pero a la hora de realizar la suma no se porque interpeta de esa manera mi opreación, y estaria buscando la manera de que los resultados sean los esperados, respecto a la operación realizada.

Comment: ¿Has probado a insertar la línea que te propongo? Así podrás ver numéricamente que operación estas realizando, teniendo en cuenta las prioridades de los operadores donde el paréntesis iría primero, luego la multiplicación y por ultimo la suma.

Comment: ya he podido, gracias a esa linea, te lo agradezco Arkk92